# How can i call a Procedure with OUT parameter in postgreSQL 13

Tags: sql, postgresql

Output Type Table

```
CREATE TYPE TYP_NON_SEL_FN_RES AS(



            sin_sql_custom_status SMALLINT,
            vhr_sql_custom_status_code VARCHAR(100),
            vhr_sql_custom_message VARCHAR(1000), 
            
            vhr_sql_custom_error_type VARCHAR(100),
            vhr_sql_custom_error_code VARCHAR(100),
            
            txt_sql_sys_message TEXT,
            txt_sql_sys_exception_detail TEXT,
            txt_sql_sys_exception_hint TEXT,
        
            bin_sql_pk BIGINT,
            vhr_sql_doc_no VARCHAR(100),
            jsn_sql_values JSON
        );
```

PROCEDURE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_tmp(OUT tbl_response TYP_NON_SEL_FN_RES,
                                            sinProduct SMALLINT,
                                            vhrKey VARCHAR(10), 
                                            vhrValue VARCHAR(250)) AS $$
DECLARE

BEGIN
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO settings.tbl_tmp
            (sin_product, vhr_key, vhr_value)
        VALUES
            (sinProduct, vhrKey, vhrValue);

        COMMIT;
        tbl_response['sin_sql_custom_status'] = 1;
        
        
    EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        tbl_response['sin_sql_custom_status'] = -1;
    END;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call the PROCEDURE

```
CALL sp_tmp(output_table::TYP_NON_SEL_FN_RES, '1'::SMALLINT, 'A1'::VARCHAR(10), 'B1'::VARCHAR(250));
Error:-
------
ERROR:  column "output_table" does not exist
LINE 1: CALL sp_tmp(output_table::TYP_NON_SEL_FN_RES, '1'::SMALLINT,...
                    ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 13
```

Comment: You can not pass a "table" as a parameter in PL/pgSQL. If at all, you can pass a single record of that type. But if you want to return a table like result, use a set-returning function and use `select * from the_function(..)`

Comment: In 13, you can't get far enough to do the call, as the create fails.  `ERROR:  procedures cannot have OUT arguments
HINT:  INOUT arguments are permitted.`

Comment: Actually, I tried the function with the return. but the problem is that commit and rollback are not working in the function that's why I chose procedure